# Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\Jellyfish.jpg'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

When i ran the Project ,it shows "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\Jellyfish.jpg'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 
'C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\Jellyfish.jpg'.

```
uploadFile.SaveAs(filePatha);
db.image.Add(image);
db.Entry(image).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

where's wrong in my code

Comment: Does that file exist?  If not, then that would explain the error.

Comment: Is there a file name `Jellyfish.jpg` locate at `C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\\`

Comment: Does the user that runs the code have access to the file (assuming it exists)?

Comment: No ,there is no file named jellyfish.jpg

Comment: Please check the filepath is null or not. You can achieve this like if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath)){//...logic}else{//do rest of the things..}

Answer (score 1):

The exception message: "Could not find a part of the path ..." is the message of the `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

In order to save a file you have to ensure that the directory exists first!

Run this before you save the file:

```
if(!Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\"))
{
 Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\shyful\Desktop\MvcApp\MvcApp\Person\Upload\");
}
```